# Why do I have so much free space on the left-hand side of my tikz diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Inspired by [How do you draw the "snake" arrow for the connecting homomorphism in the snake lemma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/) I created my own snake like diagram (see below).

The entries are rather large and the figure thus too wide. My question is: Why does the figure start only almost in the middle of the page and not on the left-hand side? *Why is there so much free space on the left?*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[descr/.style={fill=white,inner sep=1.5pt}]
        \matrix (m) [
            matrix of math nodes,
             row sep=1em,
             column sep=2em,
        ]
        { Q_{5}\oplus\bigoplus_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{12345\setminus i}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{l\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{l5}\oplus Q_{12345}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{j\neq k\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{jk5} \\
          \bigoplus_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{12345\setminus i} &
        Q_{12345} &
        S_{12345} \\
        };
        \path[->, font=\scriptsize,>=latex]
        (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
        (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
        (m-1-3) edge[out=355,in=175] (m-2-1)
    (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2)
        (m-2-2) edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, please help me to get my code block rendered appropriately! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed. For future reference: To insert a block of code, you can either pre-indent each line by 4 spaces, or, after entering the block, highlight the block and click on the "101010" symbol above the TextField.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something about the curvy edge is increasing the bounding box by a lot.  This could be considered a bug.  To cancel that effect, add `overlay` to the options for the `\path` which draws the arrows.

You might also consider using `\limits` for your `\bigoplus`es and `\mathclap` ([reference](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf)) to get the subscripts taking up less space.  Here's my version:

```
\def\mathclap{\mathpalette\mathclapinternal}
\def\mathclapinternal#1#2{\clap{$\mathsurround=0pt#1{#2}$}}
\let\oldbigoplus=\bigoplus
\def\bigoplus{\oldbigoplus\limits}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture=true]
        \matrix (m) [
            matrix of math nodes,
             row sep=1em,
             column sep=2em,
             text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex
        ]
        {Q_{5}\oplus\bigoplus_{\mathclap{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{12345\setminus i}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{\mathclap{l\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{l5}\oplus Q_{12345}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{\mathclap{j\neq k\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{jk5} \\
          \bigoplus_{\mathclap{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{12345\setminus i} &
        Q_{12345} &
        S_{12345} \\
        };
        \path[overlay,->, font=\scriptsize,>=latex]
        (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
        (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
        (m-1-3) edge[out=348,in=172] (m-2-1)
        (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2)
        (m-2-2) edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: diagram]

PS: Your `descr/.style=...` declaration has no effect unless you are actually applying the style to something.  So you can cut that out for minimal example purposes.

**Edit**: I have incorporated @Caramdir's suggested edits.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but my guess would be that the control points for the Bezier curve making up the snake path were what were enlarging the picture.

Comment: @Antal: good guess.

Answer (score 5):

Some additional small improvements on Matthew's version: In the original example I removed `text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex` which I usually add to center the arrows on complicated the text. However, it is necessary here. Also the starting and ending directions of the curved arrow need to be tweaked a little bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools} %mathtools provides \mathclap
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\let\oldbigoplus=\bigoplus
\def\bigoplus{\oldbigoplus\limits}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [
            matrix of math nodes,
            row sep=2.5em,
            column sep=2em,
            text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex
        ]
        {Q_{5}\oplus\bigoplus_{\mathclap{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{12345\setminus i}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{\mathclap{l\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{l5}\oplus Q_{12345}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{\mathclap{j\neq k\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{jk5} \\
          \bigoplus_{\mathclap{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}}} Q_{12345\setminus i} &
        Q_{12345} &
        S_{12345} \\
        };

        \path[overlay,->, font=\scriptsize,>=latex]
        (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
        (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
        (m-1-3) edge[out=348,in=172] (m-2-1)
        (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2)
        (m-2-2) edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered code]

Comment: Nice.  I thought about moving the arrows up to align with the center of the opluses but didn't know how best to do it.

Comment: @Matthew: I favor using the `mid east` and `mid west` anchors for this purpose, which eliminates dimension-guessing but requires me to put anchors in just about every coordinate.  I wonder if there is an edge style that can do this?

Answer (score 4):

It is most definitely the curvy path which is pushing things out.  To see this, you can draw the bounding box at a particular point by writing:

```
\draw (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
```

at appropriate junctures, say after the `\matrix` and after the `\path` commands.  Note that this draws the *current* bounding box so putting it at different places shows how the bounding box changes during the diagram.

As an alternative solution, the `\useasboundingbox` sets the bounding box for the picture.  To be accurate, it means that as far as the bounding box is concerned everything after this command gets ignored.  So putting it after the matrix command but before the path command means that the matrix gets used for the bounding box but the path doesn't.  Thus my soution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[scale=.96]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix (m) [
            matrix of math nodes,
             row sep=2em,
             column sep=2em,
        ]
        { Q_{5}\oplus\bigoplus_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{12345\setminus i}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{l\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{l5}\oplus Q_{12345}[1] &
        \bigoplus_{j\neq k\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{jk5} \\
          \bigoplus_{i\in\{1,2,3,4\}} Q_{12345\setminus i} &
        Q_{12345} &
        S_{12345} \\
        };
        \useasboundingbox (0,0);
        \path[->, font=\scriptsize,>=latex]
        (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
        (m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
        (m-1-3) edge[out=355,in=175] (m-2-1)
    (m-2-1) edge (m-2-2)
        (m-2-2) edge (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The effect of the `overlay` tag is similar.  That tag removes the path from the bounding box consideration, whereas the `\useasboundingbox` removes everything after it (but not including itself).