# Clip, but add arrowheads to end of clipped curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$}; 
\draw[<->,domain=-5:5,smooth,variable=\t]
    plot (\t, {pow(\t,2)});
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Is it possible to add arrowheads to the ends of the parabola after it has been clipped?

Comment: This is basically the same problem as in [How to keep the line cap when clipping a path?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127542) Why don’t you do `domain=-sqrt 5:sqrt 5` (yes, that gets more complicated with more complex functions) or use `pgfplots` (see linked question)?