# TikZ \draw (a) to (b) extends the picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, draw

So I wanted to have my `tikzpicture` inside a box, but whenever I used `\draw (a) to[out=0, in=180] (b)` it would extend the picture from initially a 14x8 picture to something wider, and the centering would look weird. I have tried other things than the `\draw (a) to[out=0, in=180] (b)`, but it is just not looking good.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \def\LB{(L1) -- ++(-7:6)}
    \def\Lb{(L2) -- ++( 7:6)}
    
    \coordinate (CStart) at (7,3);
    \path (CStart) -- ++(0,-0.5) coordinate (L1);
    \path (L1) -- ++(0, -1) coordinate (L2);
    \path[name path=LB1] \LB;
    \path[name path=LB2] \Lb;
    \path[name intersections={of=LB1 and LB2, by=P}];
    \path (P) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate (F);
    \path (CStart) -- ++(-4,0) coordinate (CDashed);
    \path (CDashed) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate (CBott);
    \path (CStart) -- ++(0,-1) coordinate (CTop);
    
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] \LB;
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] \Lb;
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (L1) -- ++(-4,0);
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (L2) -- ++(-4,0);
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (5.65,6.35) to[out=0,in=180,looseness=3] (3,1.5);
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (5.85,6.65) to[out=0,in=180,looseness=3] (3,2.5);
    
    \fill[right color=gray!50!black,left color=gray!10,middle color=gray,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (CBott) circle (0.5 and 1);
    \fill[top color=gray!50!black,bottom color=gray!50!black,middle color=gray!50,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (3,1) -- ++(4,0) arc (270:90:0.5 and 1) -- (CDashed) arc (90:-90:0.5 and 1);
    \fill[left color=gray!90!,right color=gray!2,middle color=gray!30,shading=axis,opacity=0.25] (CTop) circle (0.5 and 1);
    
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (14,8);
    \draw[decorate with=dart] (F) -- ++(0,2);
    \draw (CStart) -- ++(-4,0) arc (90:270:0.5 and 1) -- ++(4,0) ++ (0,1) circle (0.5 and 1);
    \draw[densely dashed] (CDashed) arc (90:-90:0.5 and 1);
    
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (3,6.5) -- ++(2,0);
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (5,6.5) -- (5.65,6.35);
    \draw[line width = 1.5, green] (5,6.5) -- (5.85,6.65);
    
    \filldraw[fill=black!40,draw=black!80] 
        (1,7) rectangle ++(2,-1);
    
    \fill[top color=gray!60,opacity=0.15] (4,6) -- ++(1.5,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- (4,6);
    \fill[color=gray!30!black,opacity=0.15] (5.5,6) -- ++(0.5,0.5) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(-0.5,-0.5) -- (5.5,6);
    \fill[color=gray!80,opacity=0.15] (4,6) -- ++(1.5,0.5) -- ++(0.5,0.5) -- ++(-1.5,-0.5) -- ++(-0.5,-0.5);
        
    \draw (4,6) -- ++(1.5,0) -- ++(0,0.5) -- (4,6) -- ++(0.5,0.5) -- ++(1.5,0.5) -- ++(0,-0.5) -- ++(-0.5,-0.5) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(0.5,0.5);
    
    \node[below] at (4.75,6) {Bragg cell};
    \node[below] at (5,1) {\ac{LDA}-probe};
    \node[below] at (2,6) {Laser};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:Theo/Actual probe}
\end{figure}<br/>
```

The curved green lines look how I want them to look, but they seem to extend the picture beyond the box I have drawn and now it is not centered anymore. The first image shows how I intend the picture to look with the curved lines, and the second image shows how I want the centering to look.
[image: The picture should be centered here.]

[image: As it is the case here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay nevermind, I found the solution:
Just insert the bordering rectangle as `\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (14,8);`, it gets rid of everything outside of it, meaning centering will work as thought again.
I found it in  [Caramdir's answer to Freddie's Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/tikz-cropping-the-bounding-box?rq=1).