# Align edges with anchor other than center

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

It seems that, when drawing an edge between two nodes, TikZ defaults to aligning the edge with the 'center' anchors of the two nodes. More precisely, the edge points from the center of one node to the center of the other node, and the endpoints of the edge sit on the boundary of the nodes. An example is the black arrow in the following diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep={4em,between origins},column sep={5em,between origins},nodes={anchor=mid}]{
    A^B & A_B \\
        & E   \\};
  \draw[->] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
  \draw[->,red] (m-1-1.mid) -- (m-2-2.mid);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result picture]

On the other hand, the red arrow joins the 'mid' anchors of two nodes. I would like to shorten the red arrow to make it start and end at the boundaries of the nodes (like the black arrow does). Nevertheless, I want the desired shortened arrow to stay on the same line as the above red arrow, and to still have an arrowhead (so simply clipping does not seem to do the trick).

Is there a simple way to shorten the red arrow as requested? Does anyone know how TikZ does it for the black arrow?

Comment: It would be interesting to give a minimal example!

Comment: Altermundus' intersection example works with arrows. Also you could use the `shorten >=...` syntax.

Comment: For commutative diagrams, you should either add something like `[text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]` or `[nodes={anchor=center}]` to the matrix, so that the arrows are not slanted, see the two example in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/

Comment: @Caramdir: Unfortunately, anchoring the nodes at the center causes the text of different nodes to not be vertically aligned. Also, using the options 'text height' and 'text depth' causes the arrows to behave poorly with respect to the actual border of the text in the nodes.

Comment: @Ricardo: true. Setting height and depth usually works though (if the matrix contains complicated nodes, you might have to adjust the values).

Comment: @Caramdir: Indeed, I could play with the values of the text height and text depth (instead of just giving the same for every node). I will look into that. Thanks. Nevertheless, my question is not quite about that. I have removed the remark on the arrow being slanted.

Comment: To answer your question about how TikZ calculates the black arrow: There is a special test in the code of `line to` (and similar commands). For details see `texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex`. For `line to`, the code is in `\tikz@@lineto`, which (in v2.10) starts at line 2187.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly the question . I understand that :
you want an edge between two nodes but you want to draw the edge only between the intersections of the edges and the shapes of the nodes.

With intersections (the problem is to make a choice between the points) but in the second method I just fill the node's background.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name path= c1] (foo)  at (0,0)[circle] {$x$};
  \node[name path= c2] (bar) at (2,2)[circle] {$x+1$};
  \path[name path=line] (foo.south) -- (bar.center);
  \fill [name intersections={of=c1 and line, name=i, total=\t}]
 [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}] 
 \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {}};
  \fill [name intersections={of=c2 and line, name=j, total=\t}]
 [red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}] 
 \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(j-\s) circle (2pt) node {}};   
  \draw[red] (i-1) -- (j-1);  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name path= c1] (foo)  at (0,0)[circle] {$x$};
  \node[name path= c2] (bar) at (2,2)[circle] {$x+1$};
  \path[name path=line] (foo.south) -- (bar.center);
  \path [name intersections={of=c1 and line, name=i, total=\t}] ;
  \path [name intersections={of=c2 and line, name=j, total=\t}];  
  \draw[red] (i-1) -- (j-1);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (foo)  at (0,0)[circle] {\hphantom{$x$}};
  \node (bar) at (2,2)[circle] {\hphantom{$x+1$}};
  \draw[red] (foo.south) -- (bar.center);
  \node[circle,fill=white] at (foo.center){$x$} ;
  \node[circle,fill=white] at (bar.center){$x+1$} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this won't work if the background is complicated. Could you make the circles transparent and then draw the line _under_ them?

Comment: @Seamus Yes but it's possible to use `layers` if the background is complicated but the problem is the same with the clip. You may need  another clip zone  ! example you can't add `  \path[clip] (1,1) circle(.2cm); `

Comment: @Seamus Intersection is easy if the edge starts and ends at the origins of the shapes. In this case we can use `\pgfpointborderellipse or \pgfpointborderrectangle` (Points on Borders of Objects in the pgfmanual)

Comment: In order to solve my modified question above, how would one change this answer to instead use the border (not drawn) of a math node (as in the question)?

Comment: @Ricardo You need only to remove the `draw` option in the style of nodes. I modified my version .You can also remove the red circle, I will add an example.

Answer (score 4):

Thinking about this mathematically, it is going to be very hard to do properly.  I mean, so that `\draw[->] (a) -- (b);` draws an arrow from `a` towards the desired point on `b` and stops at the boundary *with the arrowhead*.  To do that, one is going to have to calculate the point on the boundary where the line from `a` to the anchor of `b` reaches the boundary of `b` and that will depend on many parameters.

Here's a slightly different approach, which is presented more as a "proof of concept" than as usable code.  The idea is that for a simple shape such as a rectangle, one can define some auxiliary nodes whose boundary coincides with the boundary of the original node when seen from certain directions but which are centred at the correct place.  The trick is then to pick the right one of these auxiliary nodes upon approach (this is the main bit that I haven't thought how to do).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newlength\relocate@minx
\newlength\relocate@maxx
\newlength\relocate@miny
\newlength\relocate@maxy
\def\relocatenode#1#2{%
  \path (#1.south east);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\relocate@east}{\relocate@south}
  \path (#1.north west);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\relocate@west}{\relocate@north}
  \path (#1) ++(#2);
  \pgfgetlastxy{\relocate@x}{\relocate@y}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\relocate@minx}{2 * min(\relocate@east - \relocate@x, \relocate@x - \relocate@west)}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\relocate@maxx}{2 * max(\relocate@east - \relocate@x, \relocate@x - \relocate@west)}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\relocate@miny}{2 * min(\relocate@north - \relocate@y, \relocate@y - \relocate@south)}
  \pgfmathsetlength{\relocate@maxy}{2 * max(\relocate@north - \relocate@y, \relocate@y - \relocate@south)}
  \path (#1) ++(#2) node[minimum width=\relocate@minx,minimum height=\relocate@miny] (#1-minx-miny) {};
  \path (#1) ++(#2) node[minimum width=\relocate@maxx,minimum height=\relocate@miny] (#1-maxx-miny) {};
  \path (#1) ++(#2) node[minimum width=\relocate@minx,minimum height=\relocate@maxy] (#1-minx-maxy) {};
  \path (#1) ++(#2) node[minimum width=\relocate@maxx,minimum height=\relocate@maxy] (#1-maxx-maxy) {};
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={->}]
\node[draw,align=left] (a) at (0,0) {hello world\\greetings mars};
\relocatenode{a}{1,.3}
\fill (a) circle (2pt);
\fill (a) ++(1,.3) circle (2pt);

\path (a) ++(1,.3) node (b) {};

\foreach \pt in {30,60,...,360} {
  \draw (a) ++(\pt:5) -- (a);
}

\foreach \pt in {0,10,...,80} {
  \draw[red] (a) ++(\pt:5) -- (a-minx-miny);
}
\foreach \pt in {90,100,...,170} {
  \draw[red] (a) ++(\pt:5) -- (a-maxx-miny);
}
\foreach \pt in {180,190,...,260} {
  \draw[red] (a) ++(\pt:5) -- (a-maxx-maxy);
}
\foreach \pt in {270,280,...,360} {
  \draw[red] (a) ++(\pt:5) -- (a-minx-maxy);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: relocated node]

Comment: That was a very good interpretation of my ultimate goals, even though I did not state them. Indeed, I do want to draw arrows and not just segments, in the way you state.

Answer (score 3):

Is this the sort of thing you want? I've replaced the code with an example closer to the sort of thing mentioned in the question.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node (b)  [below=of a] {B};
  \node (c)  [right=of a] {C};
  \node (d)  [right=of b] {D};
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (a.north east) -- (a.east) -- (a.south east) -- (c.south west) -- (c.west) -- (c.north west) -- (a.north east);
    \draw (a.mid) -- (c.mid);
    \draw[red] (a)--(c);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (a.south) -- (a.south east) -- (a.east) --(d.north) -- (d.north west) -- (d.west) -- (a.south);
    \draw (a.mid) -- (d.mid);
    \draw[red] (a)--(d);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Better image]

The trick is to clip to a box around the relevant anchors, but keep the clip within a `scope` so the whole picture doesn't get clipped...

Comment: I think that the line to the lower node ought to stop where it first hits the boundary.  (Incidentally, I see horrible black lines on the right and lower edge of your picture but don't see them in the code.)

Comment: No. That unites two anchors, allowing it to intercept the boundaries of the nodes somewhere in the middle. I do not want that. Also, the case I have in mind would have the anchors placed within the nodes (I specifically mentioned the 'mid' anchor in my question).

Comment: @Andrew yes, I used the  standalone environment, and then wasn't very good at selecting an area for a screenshot, so I caught some of the border...

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully my question is clearer now.

Comment: @Ricardo I see. I think clipping is easier than intersections. It's just a matter of working out which anchors your clip needs to visit...

Comment: Now what would be cool is if tikz could work out the direction of your path and set up the clip automatically! Any takers?

Comment: Or maybe what you want to do is [invert clip](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12010/215) to paths going all the way round each anchor on the node. That might be easier...

Comment: For the first one you could also use the `mid east` and `mid west` anchors instead of clipping.

Comment: @Caramdir I didn't know that! Apart from the compass points and `mid` what anchors are there?

Comment: See the “Shape Library” section of the TikZ manual (chapter 48 in v2.10). Very useful are `base` and `base east/west`.