# Better arrowheads in commutative diagrams

Tags: fonts, diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

The Fourier package gives a different look for the arrowheads, which looks nice to me. I also want to use this arrowhead in the commutative diagrams. I have tried Taylor's diagrams package, xy-matrix, but the arrowheads they produce is not the type I want. The best one is the Stealth style arrowhead from tikz. Since I only need simple diagrams, I really don't want to be tortured by tikz complicated syntax. Is it possible to transplant this Stealth style to diagrams or xy-matrix?

Answer (score 11):

TikZ's syntax is complicated because it's *powerful*. You may only want a simple diagram now, but later on, you'll hit the edge of what's possible with `xy`. I'd recommend learning the basics of TikZ, the effort will repay itself as soon as you want to draw anything [complicated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-you-draw-the-snake-arrow-for-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-the-snake-le/3894#3894).

And anyway, TikZ syntax isn't *that* complicated for simple diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Tell it where the nodes are
  \node (A) {$A$};
  \node (B) [below=of A] {$B$};
  \node (C) [right=of A] {$C$};
  \node (D) [right=of B] {$D$};
  % Tell it what arrows to draw
  \draw[-stealth] (A)-- node[left] {\small $f$} (B);
  \draw[-stealth] (B)-- node [below] {\small $g$} (D);
  \draw[-stealth] (A)-- node [above] {\small $h$} (C);
  \draw[-stealth] (C)-- node [right] {\small $k$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: commutative diagram]

And you can make things easier by specifying at the start that all paths should have the `[-stealth]` decoration and so on...

Comment: And if you prefer the matrix based `xy` approach, you can do that with tikz too...

Answer (score 1):

With `\usepackage[tips]{xy}`, you can try `\SelectTips{cm}{10}`.

Where `cm`stand for computer modern and 10 for the font size.
The possible variations are `eu`(for Euler), `lu` (for Lucida) and `xy`.
For the size, you only have — according to the manual — the choice between 10, 11 or 12.

But you can do even more and define new type style, for example :

```
\newdir{|>}{*{\alpha}}
\xymatrix{
 A \ar@{|>} [r] & B }
```

gives you something like that : `A –α B`.

For more reference, see the [xyguide](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf) sections 2.2 and 2.9