# Heavy arrow tips for xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic, graphs

Arrows in `xy-pic` have narrow heads, but I need heavy tips for my graphs. I tried the following arrow definition, but the tip of the arrow enters into the circle of graph node.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\newdir{|>}{%
!/4.5pt/@{|}*:(1,-.2)@^{>}*:(1,+.2)@_{>}}

\begin{document}
\[
\xygraph{
!{<0cm,0cm>;<2cm,0cm>:<0cm,2cm>::}
!{(0,0)}*+=[o]+[F]{1}="1"
!{(1,0)}*+=[o]+[F]{2}="2"
"1":@{|>}"2"
} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Would you please help me to avoid this problem?

How can I fill insdie the arrow tip? Or preferably get something like: [image: Arrow tips]

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can draw also XY-diagrams with tikz (eg: http://www.felixl.de/commu.pdf, or [Better arrowheads in commutative diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21416)

Comment: Just an addition to JLDiaz comment: based on TikZ there's also the [tikz-cd](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package.

Comment: Thanks for links. Both stealth- and latex-style arrows in TikZ are great for my purpose. However, it is not convinient to reporoduce \xygraph{} drawings in TikZ that I am not familiar with.

Comment: Perhaps this answer would give you ideas:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/stealth-arrow-in-math/113472#113472.  There, a "stealth arrow" was added to the pre-existing font.  Perhaps the stealth arrows would be an improvement, or if still not adequate, the answer might give direction on how to do this for another font set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in order to show the solution of your problem with `tikz-cd`:

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\tikz{\node[draw, circle]{1}} \arrow[-latex]{r} & \tikz{\node[draw, circle]{2}}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\tikzcdset{
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={>=stealth}
}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\tikz{\node[draw, circle]{1}} \arrow{r} & \tikz{\node[draw, circle]{2}}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It ssems that there is no direct answer using the xy-pic package. I accept your answer to close this question.