# Stealth arrow in math?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

Is there an easy way to produce `stealth` style arrows in normal `math mode`? By "`stealth`" I'm thinking of `TikZ` `stealth` arrowhead. Something like `\rightarrowstealth`?

The question originates from a limit I'm writing. I find the arrowhead of `\rightarrow` (and the rest of the arrows, honestly) being somewhat less esthetic compared to the `TikZ` `stealth` arrowhead. I checked @Qrrbrbirlbel's comment, and I don't believe the arrowhead I'm looking for is listed.

[image]

Stevens comment fixes my problem, though! `mathabx`'s `\rightarrow` arrowhead is indeed close enough to `TikZ`'s `stealth` arrowheads for my purposes.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with `stealth`. There are many arrows available in math-mode. Have you checked the arrow section in [`symbols-a4.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)?

Comment: The `mathabx` package has some stealth-like arrow designs, designated as `\rightarrow`, `\leftarrow`, and many others...

Comment: Close enough, @StevenB.Segletes ! Post as answer, and you'll get the credz!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the `mathabx` package, a number of stealth-like arrows are available, including these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
\[x \rightarrow y\]
\[y \leftarrow y\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

FOLLOW UP:  In response to egreg's comment about *many* symbols being replaced with the mathabx package, and stealing code from Alan Munn at [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font), one can import just the two arrow symbols, if one wishes to not change other symbols to mathabx.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Setup the matha font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varleftarrow}{3}{matha}{"D0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrightarrow}{3}{matha}{"D1}
\begin{document}

Computer Modern subset
\[
A \rightarrow B
\]

\texttt{mathabx} subset

\[
A \varrightarrow B
\]
\[
B \varleftarrow A
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has the obvious issue that *many* symbols change their shape.

Comment: @egreg Fixed.  Thanks for pushing me to look for a fix.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean the `stealth` as in the arrow head style of Tikz, the package `tikz-cd` provides such an interface:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} 
\tikzset{
  commutative diagrams/.cd, 
  arrow style=tikz, 
  diagrams={>=stealth}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd} 
     A \arrow{r} &B
  \end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

**Here is the output I get:**

[image: tikzarrows.png]

Note that this is <strike>as versatile as the `mathmode`</strike> in that, you can have the `tikz-cd` environment both inline [default] and as display. Further, this is highly customisable: you can decrease the distance between the rows, between the columns, and so on.

I'd suggest that, you read `tikz-cd` [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz-cd), which is very well-written.