# Inline arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to achieve an arrow that I can use inline, ie. somewhere in the running text, similar to `\xrightarrow`, but with an open triangle as its arrow head.

This is what I came up with using tikz:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand*{\ident}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\tikzstyle{refines} = [->, >=open triangle 45]

\newcommand{\refi}[3]{$\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.63ex]%
\node (A) {#1};%
\node (B) [right of=A, node distance=4em] {#3};%
\draw[refines] (A) -- node[midway,above=-2pt] {#2} (B);%
\end{tikzpicture}$}

\begin{document}

this is a test \refi{\ident{1}}{\scriptsize text}{\ident{2}}\ident{2} that continues here

this is a test \refi{1}{\scriptsize text}{1}\ident{2} that continues here

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

However, as illustrated in the second example, the baseline is dependent on the font size I use in the picture, which is less than ideal. Moreover, I also got the width of the arrow only by trial and error. How can I repair those two problems, or get what I want in some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `anchor=base` to your nodes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand*{\ident}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\tikzstyle{refines} = [->, >=open triangle 45]

\newcommand{\refi}[3]{$\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%
\node[anchor=base] (A) {#1};%
\node[anchor=base] (B) [right of=A, node distance=4em] {#3};%
\draw[refines] (A) -- node[midway,above=-2pt] {#2} (B);%
\end{tikzpicture}$}

\begin{document}

this is a test \refi{\ident{1}}{\scriptsize text}{\ident{2}}\ident{2} that continues here

this is a test \refi{1}{\scriptsize text}{1}\ident{2} that continues here

\end{document}
```

This ensures that the baseline of the text in the node sits at level `0`.

However, there are two problems: firstly, as @rainer says, depth and height of material in the nodes can make the arrow stop being horizontal; secondly, your code does nothing in the direction of providing an exensible arrow that stretches with the material above the arrow.

The first problem could be used by using the nice `tikz-cd` package, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113449/15925.  But that won't solve the second one.  So I think it is easier let `tikz` take care of only the arrow and the text above it, and leave the rest to ordinary maths placement:

[image: Sample extending arrow]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand*{\ident}[1]{\texttt{\small #1}}

\tikzstyle{refines} = [->, >=open triangle 45]

\newsavebox{\mytempbox}
\newcommand{\refi}[3]{%
  \sbox{\mytempbox}{\hbox{\( \scriptstyle\mkern5mu#2\mkern17mu \)}}
  \( #1
  \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\draw[refines] (0,0) --
    node[midway,above=-0.3ex]{\usebox\mytempbox} (\wd\mytempbox,0);}
  #3 \)}

\begin{document}

This is a test \refi{\ident{1}}{\text{text}}{\ident{2}}\ident{2} that continues here.

This is a test \refi{1}{\text{longer text}}{1} that continues here.

A further test \refi{j_2}{\alpha-x e^{p/q}}{a^2} with more text.

\end{document}
```

The technique here is to save the material to place above the arrow in a box (I written this assuming it is math mode material).  That box is then used to specify the length of the arrow and its contents are placed above the arrow.  I have added sufficient space around the text so that overlap with the rather large arrow head does not occur.

Comment: Just as an addition if anyone ever needs this: I had to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,every node/.append style={text depth=0}]` to make this work correctly with left/right operands that have descenders.