# How to use a custom, scalable, symbol in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, symbols, svg

I want to use a custom symbol in my document that is treated like any other letter or math symbol by LaTeX. I do *not* want to [superimpose existing symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371) in order to create a new one but rather create one from scratch.

Is there a way to just create the symbol using, say, Inkscape and tell LaTeX to print that when I call a specific macro? There is of course the possibility of using `\includegraphics[height=1em]`, but I imagine that that is not a very effective approach. Can I let LaTeX use my symbol like any other math symbol?

Do I have to [create an entire font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22487/) (consisting of only one character) or is it possible to this in a simpler manner?

Comment: The `\includegraphics` approach can be made efficient by invoking it once to set the symbol in a saved box, and then the box can be efficiently recalled at need.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes for pdflatex at least it does that anyway if you load the same image twice

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did not know that.  In that case, there is nothing not "effective" about that approach, other than a `\raisebox` may be required if the new symbol is a descender.

Comment: @schtreber You could also export some svg from Inkscape using http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/ and then define a macro which you can use like here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116324

Comment: You could have a look at the technique I used here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188705/34551

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This solution demonstrates how an `\includegraphics` approach could be made to work conveniently.

If the new symbol should conform to the vertical extent of an existing glyph, then this approach will work handily.  In the MWE, I make the symbol `\schtreber` conform to the height of a "b" and then a "g", respectively.  It will scale with math style.

If the symbol is a relation or operator, the definition could include a `\mathrel` or `\mathop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\def\schtreber{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{schtreber}}{b}}

$ab\schtreber c \scriptscriptstyle ab\schtreber c$

$ y = x^{\schtreber}$

\def\schtreber{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{schtreber}}{g}}

$ab\schtreber c \scriptscriptstyle ab\schtreber c$

$ y = x^{\schtreber}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the vertical extent is to be arbitrary, a `\rule` may be used for the target size, where `\LMpt` (local-mathstyle pts) or `\LMex` (local-mathstyle ex's) are used to define the dimensions of the rule.  Here I place the image in a `\savebox` initially, in the event that some flavors of TeX don't save a local copy from `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newsavebox\schtreberbox
\savebox\schtreberbox{\includegraphics{schtreber}}
\def\schtreber{\scalerel{\usebox{\schtreberbox}}{\rule[-2\LMpt]{0pt}{8\LMpt}}}
\begin{document}
$ab\schtreber c \scriptscriptstyle ab\schtreber c$\par
$ y = x^{\schtreber}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of the former, rather than the latter approach is that the method will also work in both text and math mode, as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newsavebox\schtreberbox
\savebox\schtreberbox{\includegraphics{schtreber}}
\def\schtreber{\scalerel*{\usebox{\schtreberbox}}{b}}
\begin{document}
$ab\schtreber c \scriptscriptstyle ab\schtreber c$\par
$ y = x^{\schtreber}$

In text\schtreber, \LARGE text\schtreber.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would have been nicer if schtreber was an `eps` or `svg` file…

Comment: @Clément This example was for illustrative purposes.  The graphics format is irrelevant to `scalerel` but obviously must be compatible with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Clément I would add that even `\includegraphics` is not a requirement for this approach.  Any graphic that can be placed into a LaTeX box would work.

Comment: There is no space after the symbol, how do I fix it?

Comment: @Ziofil You can either edit the image to add a little horizontal space (called sidebearing), or you can add space to the definition: `\def\schtreber{\kern1pt\scalerel*{\usebox{\schtreberbox}}{b}\kern1pt}`