# Symbol creation in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I've come up with a way of displaying the symbol my lecturer uses for a poset embedding in LaTeX, having not been able to find it as a standard symbol.  The method I employed was using a TikZ picture as a new function with the following code

```
\newcommand{\Sqsubset}{
\kern3pt
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0ex,0ex) -- (0ex,1.3ex);
\draw (0ex,0) -- (1.3ex,0ex);
\draw (0ex,1.3ex) -- (1.3ex,1.3ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (1.3ex,0.325ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (0.325ex,0.975ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.975ex) -- (1.3ex,0.975ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
\kern3pt }
```

I was basically just wondering if there is a way of using this symbol without having to have the compiler draw it from the code every time... perhaps saving it as a glyph?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you can include the `mathabx` package so that you can use `\sqSubset` in math mode --> [a comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175443/how-to-use-a-custom-scalable-symbol-in-latex

Comment: Can you give some reference for the symbol? I can't find it in the Unicode repertoire; with some showcases it might be included.

Comment: @egreg -- not in unicode.  wasn't on the stix list.  if a published reference can be found, it would certainly be accepted, and i'd be happy to submit it.

Comment: @JoelCulver -- since this already exists in a tex symbol package, it clearly must be in use.  if you (or your lecturer) can provide a reference to its use in a published book or journal, preferably in a context with a clear definition, i will be happy to submit it to unicode.  (contact info in my profile.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symbol quality can be improved.

Spacings:

- `\mathrel` takes care of the horizontal math mode spacing in different
  math contexts.
- Side bearings for the symbol can be reduced from 3pt to values similar to `sqsubset`.

Line drawings:

- Polylines should not be split and the line segments drawn as single lines.
  Then line join settings does not apply. If the lines are drawn as connected
  lines, then the line joining can be made smoother. The example below uses setting `round`.
- Also the line caps can be made round as in `\sqsubset`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Old version
\newcommand{\OldSqsubset}{
\kern3pt
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0ex,0ex) -- (0ex,1.3ex);
\draw (0ex,0) -- (1.3ex,0ex);
\draw (0ex,1.3ex) -- (1.3ex,1.3ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (1.3ex,0.325ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (0.325ex,0.975ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.975ex) -- (1.3ex,0.975ex);
\end{tikzpicture}
\kern3pt }

% New version
\newcommand{\Sqsubset}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \tikz[line cap=round, line join=round]
    \draw
      (1.3ex, 0ex) -- (0ex, 0ex) -- (0ex, 1.3ex) -- (1.3ex, 1.3ex)
      (1.3ex, 0.325ex) -- (0.325ex, 0.325ex) -- (0.325ex, 0.975ex)
      -- (1.3ex, 0.975ex)
      (-.13ex, 0ex) (1.3ex + .13ex, 0ex) % side bearings
    ;%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  $A \OldSqsubset B$
  $A \Sqsubset B$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: alignment is incorrect.  should be vertically centered around the math axis.  (same alignment, and same class, as regular `\subset`.)

Answer (score 12):

Wouldn't be better to use a standard symbol?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}

\[
A\sqSubset B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can avoid `mathabx` changing all symbols, which might be undesired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
  <-5.5> mathb5
  <5.5-6.5> mathb6
  <6.5-7.5> mathb7
  <7.5-8.5> mathb8
  <8.5-9.5> mathb9
  <9.5-11> mathb10
  <11-> mathb12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqSubset}{3}{mathb}{"94}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqSupset}{3}{mathb}{"95}

\begin{document}

$A \sqSubset B \sqSupset C$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is made to obey math styles, and I called it a `\mathrel` (an assumption of mine).  It will always be as tall as the height of a capital letter.

EDITED to change the second argument of `\scalerel*` from `X` to `\subset`, so that this new symbol would forever acquire the height of `\subset`, in response to Barbara's comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}
\newcommand{\SqsubsetRAW}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0ex,0ex) -- (0ex,1.3ex);
\draw (0ex,0) -- (1.3ex,0ex);
\draw (0ex,1.3ex) -- (1.3ex,1.3ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (1.3ex,0.325ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (0.325ex,0.975ex);
\draw (0.325ex,0.975ex) -- (1.3ex,0.975ex);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\newsavebox\SqsubsetBOX
\savebox\SqsubsetBOX{\SqsubsetRAW}
\newcommand\Sqsubset{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\kern1\LMpt\usebox{\SqsubsetBOX}}{\subset}}}
\begin{document}
$Z \subset A\Sqsubset B_{A\Sqsubset B_{A\Sqsubset B}}$

\LARGE
$A\Sqsubset B_{A\Sqsubset B_{A\Sqsubset B}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: alignment is incorrect.  should be vertically centered around the math axis.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `\savebox`.  However, this may be an issue if the symbol is used in subscripts or superscripts, etc.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\SqsubsetMacro}{%
    \kern3pt
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0ex,0ex) -- (0ex,1.3ex);
    \draw (0ex,0) -- (1.3ex,0ex);
    \draw (0ex,1.3ex) -- (1.3ex,1.3ex);
    \draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (1.3ex,0.325ex);
    \draw (0.325ex,0.325ex) -- (0.325ex,0.975ex);
    \draw (0.325ex,0.975ex) -- (1.3ex,0.975ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \kern3pt%
}

\newsavebox{\SqsubsetBox}
\savebox{\SqsubsetBox}{\SqsubsetMacro}
\newcommand{\Sqsubset}{\usebox{\SqsubsetBox}}

\begin{document}

\Sqsubset  

\end{document}
```