# Creating a new symbol in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, math-operators, coding

I would like to create a symbol for a function in LaTeX, like this:
[image: Like an f for f(x)]

Can someone help me?

It would have to look like this: [image]

Comment: you can take the image you have and use it as a character via `\includegraphics[height=1.1ex]{yourimage}`

Comment: You could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336070/symbol-creation-in-tikz

Comment: David Carlisle I would like to make it nicer also.
Campanlgnis I will be looking it!

Comment: Another option is to save your image in a vector format (if that’s SVG, you can embed it into a PDF) and insert that, properly scaled to the current x-height of your font.

Comment: Nicer? Then is easy: `$\varrho$` ...

Comment: .. or even `$\descnode$` of `wasysym` package.

Answer (score 8):

I provide, at no cost to you, `\froogle`...works in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel}
\newcommand\froogle{\scalerel*{\rotatebox{90}{\raisebox{1pt}{%
  \scalebox{1}[.7]{$\varsigma$}}\kern-1.1pt\scalebox{.7}[1]{o}}}{Xg}}
\begin{document}
$\froogle(x) + A_{\froogle_{(1 + \froogle)}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change fonts, the parameters may need tweaking.  Here, I redo for `txfonts`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,scalerel,txfonts}
\newcommand\froogle{\scalerel*{\rotatebox{90}{\raisebox{1.3pt}{%
  \scalebox{.85}[.7]{$\varsigma$}}\kern-1.2pt\scalebox{.85}[1]{o}}}{Xg}}
\begin{document}
$\froogle(x) + A_{\froogle_{(1 + \froogle)}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can find three symbols that are close to one you desire.  The $\varrho$ from Fran's answer, and two *\mathfrak* characters (the g and d, transformed).
[image]

The code is here.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

$x\mapsto\varrho(x)$ 
\qquad
$x\mapsto\raisebox{-.2ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\mathfrak{d}$}}(x)$
\qquad
$x\mapsto\raisebox{.35ex}{\reflectbox{$\mathfrak{g}$}}(x)$
\end{document}
```