# Special symbols in table (filled cross, empty cross, filled square, empty square)

Tags: tables, symbols, overleaf, math-operators

I am working on a table in latex, describing the data in a figure.  It contains a number of special symbols that the figure includes, and I wanna have the same things in the table. However, I am facing difficulties in finding these symbols in different packages. Below is the raw code for the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}



\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\begin{table}[b!]
        \caption{Details of the data presented in figure 16 regarding modifications in a monodisperse suspension of large particles to replicate the settling velocity of large particles in bidisperse flows}
        \label{tab5}
%   \scriptsize
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c}\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\text{Re}_{\text{t,l}}$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Mono}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Bi}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mono, $\rho_{f,m}$} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Mono, $\rho_{f,m}$ {\&} $\mu_{f,m}$} \\
\cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & & & Value & Deviation && Value & Deviation \\ \midrule
1 & 0.6 & 0.455 & 0.576 & 26.6 && 0.445 & 2.2  \\ \midrule
50 & 0.75 & 0.72 & 0.7235 & 0.48 && 0.61 & 15.3 \\ \midrule
100 & 0.777 & 0.7354 & 0.742 & 0.89 && 0.6268 & 14.7 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The code above gives the following table:

[image: initial image]

However, I need to have a table with the symbols, as below:

[image: desired table]

The symbols are **filled red square**, **empty black square**, **filled red cross**, **empty red cross**.
These should be with the same size, color, and order as the desired image shows.

Comment: `\square`, `\blacksquare` and `\times` are fairly sstandard. The empty cross might be trickier.

Comment: Thanks. But I need them all together. Also, the line thickeness matters here, specicially for \times.

Comment: If the line thickness matters and you do not [find it in `symbols-a4.pdf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/277964), draw it using TikZ.

Comment: Thats why I posted here cuz I am not quite familiar with tikz in table. I think for the empty red cross, that works.

Comment: There are already several questions about drawing symbols using TikZ, e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336111/277964) that even shows how to use such a symbol as math relation. So you should at least show, what you've tried.

Comment: The problm is how to draw that empty red cross symbol and how to include them in a table. I don't know too much about these details.

Comment: Yout have an example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336075/90297 how to draw something with tikz and create a symbol out of it that you can later use in math mode. you need to change the `draw` commands there to create an empty X

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symbol creation in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336070/symbol-creation-in-tikz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose the parameters as you like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pict2e,xcolor}

\newcommand*{\filledredsquare}{\textcolor{red}{\mysymbols{\polygon*(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,1)\polygon(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,1)}}}
\newcommand*{\emptyblacksquare}{\mysymbols{\polygon(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,1)}}
\newcommand*{\filledredcross}{\textcolor{red}{\mysymbols{\Line(0,0)(1,1)\Line(0,1)(1,0)}}}
\newcommand*{\emptyredcross}{\textcolor{red}{\mysymbols{\linethickness{.2pt}\polygon(.1,0)(1,.9)(.9,1)(0,.1)\polygon(.9,0)(1,.1)(.1,1)(0,.9)}}}

\newcommand*{\mysymbols}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \setlength{\unitlength}{1.3ex}% or a value you like
   \begin{picture}(1,1)
   \thicklines
   #1%
   \end{picture}%
   \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
zzz \filledredsquare\ \emptyblacksquare\ \filledredcross\ \emptyredcross\  zzz
\end{document}
```

[image]