# Squiggly arrows with tail or two heads with/without tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm using squiggly arrows with two heads or with tails in diagrams with `tikz-cd`, and I'd like to use similar-looking arrows inline. I know that there are e.g. `\rightsquigarrow` and `\rightarrowtail` in `amsmath`, but I couldn't find a squiggly arrow with a tail in the symbol list.

What's the easiest way to get such arrows (squiggly with tail or two heads)? I've found answers on how to use inline tikz diagrams for arrows with labels [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116322/inline-arrows-with-tikz) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60216/how-to-create-a-squiggle-arrow-with-some-text-on-it-in-tikz), but this looks pretty complicated and I don't need labels.

Is there a  simple and performant way of using tikz arrow shapes inline? Or how else could I create the desired arrows?

Comment: Unicode defines some squiggly arrows: ⟿⬳⬿⇜⇝. Try out some of the OTF math fonts: texmf `/fonts/opentype/public/...`. (the Tex Gyre ones, for example)

Answer (score 1):

The legacy font family `lasy` has a (repeatable) squiggle in it at slot 58, and arrowhead at slot 59:

[image: squiggle]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}
\xfonttable{U}{lasy}{m}{n}

\newcommand\squiggle{%
{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char58\char59}
}
\newcommand\squigglea{%
{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char58}
}
\newcommand\squiggleb{%
{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char59}
}
\newcommand\squigglec{%
{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\char58\char59\char59}
}

\squiggle :: \squigglea + \squiggleb + \squiggleb = \squigglec

\end{document}
```

Comment: great, thanks! and sorry for the late reaction. what makes this font a "legacy font"?

Comment: "Legacy" used rather loosely for 128 or 256-slot fontfile accessed via NFSS method, rather than a .ttf/.otf (Unicode) font accessed by name via `fontspec`. More specifically, in this case, a PostScript (Adobe Type 1) font, from decades ago, made up of a set of metric files, .afm, .pfb, etc - see e.g. `...\texmf-dist\fonts\type1\public\amsfonts\latxfont\lasy10.pfm`. `ulem` package uses it for underwavy, and obsolete `latexsym` package uses the arrow-head version to define mathematical relational operator `\leadsto`.

Answer (score 1):

Note: to use squiggle arrows in `tikzcd` you must load the `decorations.pathmorphing` library. You can use `tikzcd` inline using the `cramped` option:

```
Here is an inline map \begin{tikzcd}[cramped]A\arrow[r, leftrightsquigarrow]&B\end{tikzcd} with a squiggle.
```

[image]

If you will use this construction frequently, you may want to define a macro. But then you must use `ampersand replacement`. You can do the same for `leftsquigarrow`.

[image]

To get a tail you can use `P\arrow[r, rightsquigarrow, tail]&Q`:

[image]

You can also change the arrowhead using the `squiggly` option. For example: `P\arrow[r, -stealth, squiggly, tail]`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\newcommand{\lrsquig}[2]{\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, ampersand replacement=\&]#1\arrow[r, leftrightsquigarrow]\&#2\end{tikzcd}}

\begin{document}
Here is an inline map \lrsquig{A}{B} with a squiggle. It also works in display:
\[
\lrsquig{X}{Y}
\]
Here is the next line.
\end{document}
```