# Straight math arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, arrows

Is there any way to redefine all arrows in math mode (`\rightarrow`, `\leftarrow`, `\Rightarrow`, `\Leftarrow`, `\to`, etc.) to another arrows that finish with `angle 90` TikZ option?

I have done some tries and I've got good results with normal math size:
[image]

Using the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%Redefine \rightarrow
\renewcommand{\rightarrow}{\mathbin{\tikz[baseline]\draw[arrows={-angle 90},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (.95em,0);}}

\begin{document}

%\mathchar"3221 is just the original code of \rightarrow
\noindent $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 \mathchar"3221 (x-1)^2 = 0 \mathchar"3221 x = 1$\\
$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 \rightarrow (x-1)^2 = 0 \rightarrow x = 1$

\end{document}
```

But I have problems when I use that arrow in special cases like limits, and I would like that all those arrows work in that situation (if possible):

[image]

I know that in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/stealth-arrow-in-math) is also explained how to get symbols that are like mine, but the package doesn't include the arrows that I would like to have. Also, I would like that that new arrows behave like normal characters, so if I put `$2x \textcolor{red}{\rightarrow} 0$`,  I would obtain a red arrow.

Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the tikz definition you gave doesn't scale with the smaller math styles.  To overcome that, we use the `scalerel` package to scale (on the fly) the good normal-sized arrow to the same vertical extent as the original arrow that you are replacing, *in the current math style*.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\let\svrightarrow\rightarrow
\newcommand{\TSrightarrow}{\mathbin{\tikz[baseline]\draw[arrows={-angle 90},yshift=0.75ex] (0,0) -- (.95em,0);}}
\renewcommand\rightarrow{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\TSrightarrow}{\svrightarrow}}}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 \svrightarrow (x-1)^2 = 0 \svrightarrow x = 1$\\~\\
$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 \rightarrow (x-1)^2 = 0 \rightarrow x = 1$\\~\\
\( \lim_{h\svrightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \)\\~\\
\( \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I could expand you code to generate \leftarrow and \leftrightarrow too, but, how can I do \Leftarrow, \Rightarrow and \Leftrightarrow?

Comment: @JnxF  I'm not a tikz guy, so I couldn't tell you how to draw the initial arrows.  But if you could do that in tikz, then `scalerel` should be able to scale it to the given math size.

Comment: @JnxF  Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72784/arrow-with-two-colors-with-tikz/72791#72791 would help with double arrows in tikz (repeating, I'm not a tikz person).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your arrow doesn't scale appropriately, depending on the math style. Simply using `\text` or `\mathchoice` alleviates a little the situation, but leaves a problem with the arrow tip not scaling appropriately.

Here's a definition using `\mathchoice` and a decoration, to be able to scale down the arrow tip appropriately. Perhaps some adjustments are still needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

%Redefine \rightArrow
\newcommand\rightArrow{%
\mathchoice
  {\mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline]
    \draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.88]{angle 90}}},postaction=decorate,yshift=0.75ex] 
      (0,0) -- (.95em,0);}%
  }
  {\mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline]
    \draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.88]{angle 90}}},postaction=decorate,yshift=0.75ex] 
      (0,0) -- (.95em,0);}%
  }
  {\mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline]
    \draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.6]{angle 90}}},postaction=decorate,yshift=0.43ex] 
      (0,0) -- (.65em,0);}\mkern1.8mu}
  {\mathrel{%
    \tikz[baseline]
    \draw[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=0.5]{angle 90}}},postaction=decorate,yshift=0.38ex] 
      (0,0) -- (.58em,0);}\mkern1.5mu}
}

\begin{document}

$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 \mathchar"3221 (x-1)^2 = 0 \mathchar"3221 x = 1$

$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 \rightArrow (x-1)^2 = 0 \rightArrow x = 1$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\quad A_{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}}$

$\lim_{x\rightArrow 0}\quad A_{\lim_{x\rightArrow 0}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]