# Why can't I do this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I use this code in beamer:

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90]
\matrix(a)[matrix of math nodes,
row sep=2.5em, column sep=2.5em,
text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.20ex, ampersand replacement=\&]
{\bigwedge^2 S^m\&S^m\&S\&0\\
F_2\&F_1\&S\&0\\};
\draw[->](a-1-1) -- (a-1-2);
\draw[->](a-1-2) -- (a-1-3);
\draw[->](a-1-3) -- (a-1-4);
\draw[->](a-2-1) -- (a-2-2);
\draw[->](a-2-2) -- (a-2-3);
\draw[->](a-2-3) -- (a-2-4);
\draw[->](a-1-1) -- node[auto] {$\gamma$}(a-2-1);
\draw[->](a-1-2) -- node[auto] {$\cong$}(a-2-2);
\draw[double equal sign distance,shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt](a-1-3) -- node[auto]   {$id$}(a-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
```

but I don't get the double line between (a-1-3) and (a-2-3), why?

(I took this code here: [How can I do this diagram with tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22802/how-can-i-do-this-diagram-with-tikz))

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `double equal sign distance` with `double,double distance=3pt`.  (Still not exactly this, but closer.)

A quick and dirty workaround is:

```
\draw[shorten <=5pt,shorten >=5pt,line width=3.8pt](a-1-3) -- node[auto]   {$id$}(a-2-3);
\draw[shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt,line width=3pt,color=white](a-1-3) -- node[auto]   {$id$}(a-2-3);
```

(This does a similar thing as `double`, but manually and prevents "sticking out" of the middle (white) part of the line.)

Comment: with double,double distance=3pt i get a double line but one is black and one is grey, why?

Comment: Try zooming in, this might be a low-resolution artifact.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me and I noticed a double line, as expected. It may be viewer issue.

- Try zooming in to see if the single line changes to a double line at a higher zoom level
- Try a different PDF viewer
- Print it onto paper to verify

If it's just a viewer issue you don't need to change your code. You could get around by raising distance or line thickness regarding visibilty and greyness though.