# Bending snakes with xy-pic

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

This is a follow-up to this question: [How do you draw the "snake" arrow for the connecting homomorphism in the snake lemma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-you-draw-the-snake-arrow-for-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-the-snake-l)

I'm trying to emulate this snake diagram Aluffi does in his book "Algebra, Chapter 0" with xy-pic:

[image]

but I can't modify correctly Matsaya's code to this avail. What I especially like about this diagram is the snake, crossing the diagram that way.

Comment: Could you post what you have so far? Would you be interested in a `PSTricks` or a `TikZ` answer?

Comment: @cmhughes: I never used it, but I'm of course willing to try it, and it's interesting for everybody.

Comment: It's normal you can't modify my code to do your figure, because the xy-syntaxe '^dl[dl] only permits you to draw 1/8 of circle, but you want 1/16 of circle (^dll). I will think about another way to achieve your desires.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a try.

First, the code :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}
\newcommand*\pp{{\rlap{\('\)}}}
\begin{document}
%
\[
  \xymatrix@!R{
                & 0                  & 0                  & 0                      \\
0 \ar@{-->}[r]  & {\ker(a)} \ar[r]   & {\ker(b)} \ar[r]   & {\ker(c)}
                \ar@{-}`r[d]`[d]^\delta[d] % curved arrow 1
                                                                               & \\
0 \ar@{-->}[r]  & A    \ar[r]^{f}    & B  \ar[r]^{g}      & C \ar[r]
                 \ar@{}+<0.6cm,0cm>="p1"  %intersection point 1
                                                                               & 0 \\
0 \ar[r]        & A\pp \ar[r]^{f'}
                 \ar@{}[l]+<1cm,0cm>="p2" %intersection point 2
                 \ar`_l[l]+<1.03cm,0cm>`[d]`[d][d] % curved arrow 2
                               & B\pp \ar[r]^{g'}   & C\pp \ar@{-->}[r]        & 0 \\
          & {\coker(a)} \ar[r] & {\coker(b)} \ar[r] & {\coker(c)} \ar@{-->}[r] & 0 \\
          & 0                  & 0                  & 0                            \\
% vertical arrows
\ar"1,2";"2,2"   \ar"1,3";"2,3"     \ar"1,4";"2,4"
\ar"2,2";"3,2"   \ar"2,3";"3,3"     \ar"2,4";"3,4"
\ar"3,2";"4,2"^a \ar"3,3";"4,3"^<<b \ar"3,4";"4,4"^c
\ar"4,2";"5,2"   \ar"4,3";"5,3"     \ar"4,4";"5,4"
\ar"5,2";"6,2"   \ar"5,3";"6,3"     \ar"5,4";"6,4"
% diagonal arrow, with 1 hole
\ar@{-}"p1";"p2"|!{"2,3";"3,3"}\hole
}
\]
\end{document}
```

Then some explanations.

- `\xymatrix@!R` forces all colon spaces equal
- `\newcommand*\pp{{\rlap{\('\)}}}` is to hide the prime's width (not really necessary)
- `\ar"1,3";"2,3"` is an explicit position of arrow
- `|!{[];[d]}\hole` makes a hole in the present arrow at the position where it intersects the (straight) line from `[]` to `[d]`
- `` \ar`d[t1]`[t2][t3] `` begins in the `d` direction, go to the `t1` entry, makes a quarter of turn, go to the `t2` entry, makes a quarter of turn and ends in `t3`. The `/4pt` changes the radius. It's even possible to decide the direction of the turn with `` `^d[t] `` or `` `_ul[t] `` syntax. But you are only able to do 1/8 of turn, not 1/16 as you want.
- Finally, we name the two intersection position p1 and p2 with `\ar@{}+<0.6cm,0cm>="p1"`(the finding of intersection points is done manually, but it's maybe improvable) and draw an arrow between the two points.

This version is "improved". I.e. the spacing and positioning is more consistent with your example (but the first code could be changed quite easily). I also added dashed arrow `@{-->}`(you could have dotted with `@{..>}`) and put the `b`a little upper (with `^<<b`).

You could also do it in a slightly different way and without naming points. To have the slanted arrow, simply go to the left, and then modify the target by an appropriate value (here find by hand too).
N.B. I think you only can modify the last entry of a path with the syntax +vector. So you have 
 to draw you arrow in two times.

```
\[
  \xymatrix@!{
          & {\ker(a)} \ar[r]   & {\ker(b)} \ar[r]   & {\ker(c)}
                \ar@{-}`r[d]`[d]^\delta[dll]-<1.35cm,2.315cm>|!{"2,3";"3,3"}\hole % curved arrow 1
                                                                  &   \\
          & A    \ar[r]^{f}    & B  \ar[r]^{g}      & C \ar[r]
                                                                  & 0 \\
0 \ar[r]  & A\pp \ar[r]^{f'}
                 \ar`_l[l]+<1cm,0cm>`[d]`[d][d]% curved arrow 2
                               & B\pp \ar[r]^{g'}   & C\pp        &   \\
          & {\coker(a)} \ar[r] & {\coker(b)} \ar[r] & {\coker(c)} &   \\
% vertical arrows
\ar"1,2";"2,2"   \ar"1,3";"2,3"   \ar"1,4";"2,4"
\ar"2,2";"3,2"^a \ar"2,3";"3,3"^b \ar"2,4";"3,4"^c
\ar"3,2";"4,2"   \ar"3,3";"4,3"   \ar"3,4";"4,4"
}
\]
```

For more details, see the xy-pic [user's guide](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf).

The first example :
[image: snakexy]

The second one :

[image: snakexy2]

Comment: This is great too, and with xypic! The only detail is that I was ambiguous in my comment to Andrew Stacey's answer, in that the $0\to ker(a)$ and $coker(c)\to 0$ arrows that should be dotted are the horizontal ones ;)

Comment: @BrunoStonek it's corrected, but I'm ashamed of my fault !

Comment: Very nice!  (I fixed a couple of indentation errors in the code blocks.)

Answer (score 13):

Following the comments, the OP said he might be interested in a PSTricks solution. Below is a solution using the `pst-node` package. The 'snake' curve isn't perfect- any ideas for improvement are welcome.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.75cm,yunit=1cm,nodesep=3pt}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,6)
%\psgrid    % useful during construction
% put the nodes in- working from the bottom upwards
% bottom row
\psnode(1,0){10}{$0$}
\psnode(2,0){20}{$0$}
\psnode(3,0){30}{$0$}
% second row
\psnode(1,1){cokerl}{coker $\lambda$}
\psnode(2,1){cokerm}{coker $\mu$}
\psnode(3,1){cokern}{coker $\nu$}
% third row
\psnode(0,2){02}{$0$}
\psnode(1,2){L0}{$L_0$}
\psnode(2,2){M0}{$M_0$}
\psnode(3,2){N0}{$N_0$}
\psnode(4,2){42}{$0$}
% fourth row
\psnode(0,3){03}{$0$}
\psnode(1,3){L1}{$L_1$}
\psnode(2,3){M1}{$M_1$}
\psnode(3,3){N1}{$N_1$}
\psnode(4,3){43}{$0$}
% fifth row
\psnode(0,4){04}{$0$}
\psnode(1,4){kerl}{ker $\lambda$}
\psnode(2,4){kerm}{ker $\mu$}
\psnode(3,4){kern}{ker $\nu$}
% sixth row
\psnode(1,5){15}{$0$}
\psnode(2,5){25}{$0$}
\psnode(3,5){35}{$0$}
% horizontal arrows
% 2nd row
\ncline{->}{cokerl}{cokerm}
\ncline{->}{cokerm}{cokern}
% 3rd row
\ncline{->}{02}{L0}
\ncline{->}{L0}{M0}
\nbput{$\alpha_0$}
\ncline{->}{M0}{N0}
\nbput{$\beta_0$}
\ncline{->}{N0}{42}
% 4th row
\ncline{->}{03}{L1}
\ncline{->}{L1}{M1}
\naput{$\alpha_1$}
\ncline{->}{M1}{N1}
\naput{$\beta_1$}
\ncline{->}{N1}{43}
% 5th row
\ncline{->}{04}{kerl}
\ncline{->}{kerl}{kerm}
\ncline{->}{kerm}{kern}
% vertical arrows
\ncline{->}{cokerl}{10}
\ncline{->}{cokerm}{20}
\ncline{->}{cokern}{30}
\ncline{->}{L0}{cokerl}
\ncline{->}{M0}{cokerm}
\ncline{->}{N0}{cokern}
\ncline{->}{L1}{L0}
\nbput{$\lambda$}
\ncline{->}{M1}{M0}
\nbput{$\mu$}
\ncline{->}{N1}{N0}
\nbput{$\nu$}
\ncline{->}{kerl}{L1}
\ncline{->}{kerm}{M1}
\ncline{->}{kern}{N1}
\ncline{->}{15}{kerl}
\ncline{->}{25}{kerm}
\ncline{->}{35}{kern}
\nccurve[angleA=0,angleB=180]{->}{kern}{cokerl}
% npos takes a value between 0 and 1 for \nccurve
\naput[npos=0.1]{$\delta$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

And if you change the line `\nccurve...` and `\naput...` to

```
\ncloop[angleA=0,armA=1cm,armB=1.5cm,angleB=180,loopsize=1.5,linearc=0.25]{->}{kern}{cokerl}
\naput[npos=0.4]{$\delta$}
```

then you get

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want to run the code with `pdflatex` then your preamble should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}
....
```

You should then run

```
 pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex
```

If you want to use the code 'as is', then you should either use `xelatex myfile.tex` or else

```
 latex myfile.tex
 dvips myfile.dvi
 ps2pdf myfile.ps
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to this package, and with your minimal example I'm getting "undefined control sequence" on \psnode. What's going on?

Comment: @BrunoStonek No problem. You can not compile it with `pdflatex`. You have a few choices. Either you need to use `XeLaTeX` or else `latex=>dvi=>ps=>pdf` or else see this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. After adding \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
 and running pdflatex with -shell-escape I get "Cannot determine size of graphic in a.pdf (no BoundingBox)."

Comment: @BrunoStonek I've added details to the end of my example, hope it helps.

Comment: I've closely followed your instructions for use with pdflatex but I still get the aformentioned error.

Comment: I opened a new post about it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31724/cant-use-pstricks-boundingbox-error

Answer (score 11):

Here's a modification of the TikZ version from [How do you draw the "snake" arrow for the connecting homomorphism in the snake lemma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-you-draw-the-snake-arrow-for-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-the-snake-l).  One could fine tune the spacing and curving a bit better, I guess.  Also, if I were writing it from fresh I'd label things more appropriately for *this* incantation of the snake lemma.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31687/86}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  matrix,%
  calc,%
  arrows%
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 60]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={30pt},row sep={40pt,between origins}] (s)
{
&|[name=0a]| 0 &|[name=0b]| 0 &|[name=0c]| 0 \\
%
|[name=0k]| 0 &|[name=ka]| \ker \lambda &|[name=kb]| \ker \mu &|[name=kc]| \ker \nu \\
%
|[name=0A]| 0 &|[name=A]| L_1 &|[name=B]| M_1 &|[name=C]| N_1 &|[name=01]| 0 \\
%
|[name=02]| 0 &|[name=A']| L_0 &|[name=B']| M_0 &|[name=C']| N_0 &|[name=0C']| 0 \\
%
&|[name=ca]| \coker \lambda &|[name=cb]| \coker \mu &|[name=cc]| \coker \nu &|[name=0ck]| 0 \\
%
&|[name=0ca]| 0 &|[name=0cb]| 0 &|[name=0cc]| 0 \\
%
};

% Horizontal arrows
\foreach \start/\end in {%
          0A/A,
          A/B,
          B/C,
          C/01,
          02/A',
          A'/B',
          B'/C',
          C'/0C',
          0k/ka,
          ka/kb,
          kb/kc,
          ca/cb,
          cb/cc,
          cc/0ck%
} {
  \draw[->] (\start.mid east) -- (\end.mid west);
}

% Vertical arrows
\foreach \start/\end in {%
          0a/ka,
          0b/kb,
          0c/kc,
          ka/A,
          kb/B,
          kc/C,
          A/A',
          B/B',
          C/C',
          A'/ca,
          B'/cb,
          C'/cc,
          ca/0ca,
          cb/0cb,
          cc/0cc%
} {
  \draw[->] (\start) -- (\end);
}


\path (A.mid east) -- node[auto] {\(\alpha_1\)} (B.mid west);
\path (B.mid east) -- node[auto] {\(\beta_1\)} (C.mid west);
\path (A'.mid east) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\alpha_0\)} (B'.mid west);
\path (B'.mid east) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\beta_0\)} (C'.mid west);
\path (A) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\lambda\)} (A');
\path (B) -- node[auto,swap,pos=.3] {\(\mu\)} (B');
\path (C) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\nu\)} (C');

\path (C.mid east) -- node (gap) {} (A'.mid west);

\draw[->] (kc.mid east) to[out=0,in=90] ($(kc)+(1,-.5)$) -- node[auto] {\(\delta\)} ($(C)+(1,.5)$) to[out=-90,in=0] (C.mid east) -- (gap) -- (A'.mid west) to[out=180,in=90] ($(A')+(-1.3,-.5)$) -- ($(ca)+(-1.3,.5)$) to[out=-90,in=180] (ca.mid west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And result:

[image: snake lemma, version 2]

**Edit** (in response to the comment)

To get the dashed arrows, we simply pull those ones out of the "Horizontal arrows" list and create a new loop for these, adding in the `dashed` option.  Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31687/86}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  matrix,%
  calc,%
  arrows%
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 60]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={30pt},row sep={40pt,between origins}] (s)
{
&|[name=0a]| 0 &|[name=0b]| 0 &|[name=0c]| 0 \\
%
|[name=0k]| 0 &|[name=ka]| \ker \lambda &|[name=kb]| \ker \mu &|[name=kc]| \ker \nu \\
%
|[name=0A]| 0 &|[name=A]| L_1 &|[name=B]| M_1 &|[name=C]| N_1 &|[name=01]| 0 \\
%
|[name=02]| 0 &|[name=A']| L_0 &|[name=B']| M_0 &|[name=C']| N_0 &|[name=0C']| 0 \\
%
&|[name=ca]| \coker \lambda &|[name=cb]| \coker \mu &|[name=cc]| \coker \nu &|[name=0ck]| 0 \\
%
&|[name=0ca]| 0 &|[name=0cb]| 0 &|[name=0cc]| 0 \\
%
};

% Horizontal arrows
\foreach \start/\end in {%
          A/B,
          B/C,
          C/01,
          02/A',
          A'/B',
          B'/C',
          ka/kb,
          kb/kc,
          ca/cb,
          cb/cc%
} {
  \draw[->] (\start.mid east) -- (\end.mid west);
}

% Horizontal dashed arrows
\foreach \start/\end in {%
          0k/ka,
          0A/A,
          C'/0C',
          cc/0ck%
} {
  \draw[dashed,->] (\start.mid east) -- (\end.mid west);
}

% Vertical arrows
\foreach \start/\end in {%
          0a/ka,
          0b/kb,
          0c/kc,
          ka/A,
          kb/B,
          kc/C,
          A/A',
          B/B',
          C/C',
          A'/ca,
          B'/cb,
          C'/cc,
          ca/0ca,
          cb/0cb,
          cc/0cc%
} {
  \draw[->] (\start) -- (\end);
}


\path (A.mid east) -- node[auto] {\(\alpha_1\)} (B.mid west);
\path (B.mid east) -- node[auto] {\(\beta_1\)} (C.mid west);
\path (A'.mid east) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\alpha_0\)} (B'.mid west);
\path (B'.mid east) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\beta_0\)} (C'.mid west);
\path (A) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\lambda\)} (A');
\path (B) -- node[auto,swap,pos=.3] {\(\mu\)} (B');
\path (C) -- node[auto,swap] {\(\nu\)} (C');

\path (C.mid east) -- node (gap) {} (A'.mid west);

\draw[->] (kc.mid east) to[out=0,in=90] ($(kc)+(1,-.5)$) -- node[auto] {\(\delta\)} ($(C)+(1,.5)$) to[out=-90,in=0] (C.mid east) -- (gap) -- (A'.mid west) to[out=180,in=90] ($(A')+(-1.3,-.5)$) -- ($(ca)+(-1.3,.5)$) to[out=-90,in=180] (ca.mid west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And result:

[image: Snake with dashed arrows]

Comment: Beautiful! And I can compile it without problems, too. May I ask of you to modify a little detail? Could you make the $0\to ker \lambda$, $0\to L_1$, $N_0\to 0$, $coker \nu \to 0$ dashed arrows? As you know, they are not really compulsory in the snake lemma ($\alpha_1$ monic implies $0\to ker \lambda$; $\beta_0$ epic implies $\coker \nu \to 0$). Thanks! (Sorry, but I'm not at all familiar with tikz...)

Comment: @BrunoStonek: Dashed as (I hope!) requested.

Answer (score 5):

If you cheat a little bit you can get the following figure.

[image]

I replaced @cmhuhes's following lines

```
\nccurve[angleA=0,angleB=180]{->}{kern}{cokerl}
% npos takes a value between 0 and 1 for \nccurve
\naput[npos=0.1]{$\delta$}
```

with

```
\pnode(3.5,2.8){N11}
\pnode(0.5,2.2){N12}
\nccurve[angleA=0, angleB=10]{-}{kern}{N11}
\naput[npos=0.5]{$\delta$}
\psline(3.57,2.8)(0.45,2.15)
\nccurve[angleA=-150, angleB=-180]{->}{N12}{cokerl}
```