# Bending arrows with XY

Tags: diagrams

I'm in trouble with the following diagram:

```
\[
\xymatrix{
&  & & &    & & X_1\times_Y X_2\ar@/_1pc/[dllll]\ar[dll]\ar[dddd]\\
&  & X_1 \times_Z X_2\ar[dl]\ar[rr]\ar[dd] & & X_1\ar[dd]\ar[dl] &  &\\
& Y\times_Z Y\ar[rr]\ar[dd]  & & Y\ar[dd] & & &     \\
&  & X_2 \ar[rr]\ar[dl] & & Y\ar[dl] & & \\
&  Y  \ar[rr] & & Z & & & Y\ar[lll] \ar@{-}[ull] \\
&&&&&&
}
\]
```

I would like to draw a long bending arrow from $Y$ to $Y\times_Z Y$, which goes under the last line, like I partially managed to do here with the command `` \ar `d[rr]`[llllll]`[uu]`[rrr] ``:
[image]

Unfortunately the xypic [documentation](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy-3.8.8/doc/xyguide.pdf) (par. 2.8) is as clear as the Voynich manuscript, so I'm, not able to interpret how it has to be drawn.

Comment: Is Tikz an option for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this solution with `tizk-cd` can help. The syntaxis is very much the same as `xymatrix`. The basic `xy`-command `\ar` and the directions `[u]`,...,`[r]`  are replaced by `\arrow` and `{u}`,`{d}`,`{l}`,`{r}` in curly brackets, respectively.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
&  & & &    & & X_1\times_Y X_2\\
&  & X_1 \times_Z X_2\arrow{dl}\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd} & & X_1\arrow{dd}\arrow{dl} &  &\\
& Y\times_Z Y\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd}   & & Y\arrow{dd} & & &     \\
&  & X_2\arrow{dl} \arrow{rr} & & Y\arrow{dl} & & \\
&  Y\arrow{rr}  & & Z & &  & Y 
\arrow
[to path={..controls +(-10,-1) and (-6,-3) .. (\tikztotarget)}]{uulllll}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is

```
\begin{tikzcd}
&  & & &    & & X_1\times_Y X_2\\
&  & X_1 \times_Z X_2\arrow{dl}\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd} & & X_1\arrow{dd}\arrow{dl} &  &\\
& Y\times_Z Y\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd}   & & Y\arrow{dd} & & &     \\
&  & X_2\arrow{dl} \arrow{rr} & & Y\arrow{dl} & & \\
&  Y\arrow{rr}  & & Z & &  & Y 
\arrow[to path={ (4.9,-2.8)--(4.9,-3.2)--(-5.4,-3.2)
--(-5.4,0)--(\tikztotarget)}]{uulllll}
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]
Another one

```
\begin{tikzcd}
&  & & &    & & X_1\times_Y X_2\\
&  & X_1 \times_Z X_2\arrow{dl}\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd} & & X_1\arrow{dd}\arrow{dl} &  &\\
& Y\times_Z Y\arrow{rr}\arrow{dd}   & & Y\arrow{dd} & & &     \\
&  & X_2\arrow{dl} \arrow{rr} & & Y\arrow{dl} & & \\
&  Y\arrow{rr}  & & Z & &  & Y 
\arrow[to path={ (4.9,-2.8)--(4.9,-3.2)--(-5.6,-3.2)
--(-5.6,-.6)--(\tikztotarget)}]{uulllll}
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect. The only thing I would prefer is a different kind of arrow for y -> Y x_Z Y. Does ``tikz-cd`` allow for more "polygonal" arrows?

Comment: Nothing to say, it is perfect!

Answer (score 7):

You can do this "simply" in xy by using the arrow

```
\ar`d`[llllll]`[uu][llllluu]
```

This arrows begins in the `d` direction, makes a quarter of turn, go to the `[llllll]` entry (relative position) , makes a quarter of turn, go to the `[uu]` (relative position) entry and ends in `[llllluu]` (absolute position).

For more examples and explanations, you can see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31824/3172

[image]