# How to draw bent arrows going to a new line in long formulas (ex. chain complexes)

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have to write quite long chain complexes such as

`0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow` etc.

with many terms in them, and I would like the arrows close to the side of the page to bend backwards and lead to a new line as you can see at page 31 of [these notes](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/bsmith/Math%20577.pdf) (corollary 3.4.2). 
How do I do that?

Comment: I'd suggest tikz-cd. I will write an answer for you grabbing an example from the manual...

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95770/tikz-cd-and-snake-lemma-loseness-and-centered-figures and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-you-draw-the-snake-arrow-for-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-the-snake-l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The final version is here:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
0 \rar &H^0(U \cup V) \rar & H^0(U) \oplus H^0(V) \rar
                                                  \ar[draw=none]{d}[name=X, anchor=center]{}
       & H^0(U \cap V) \ar[rounded corners,
            to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
                      |- (X.center) \tikztonodes
                      -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
                      -- (\tikztotarget)}]{dll}[at end]{\partial} \\
  {}   & H^1(U \cap V) \rar & H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) \rar 
                  \ar[draw=none]{d}[name=Y, anchor=center]{}
       & H^1(U \cap V) \ar[rounded corners,
            to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
                      |- (Y.center) \tikztonodes
                      -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
                      -- (\tikztotarget)}]{dll}[at end]{\partial} \\
  {}  & \cdots \rar & H^i(U) \oplus H^i(V) \rar 
                                          \ar[draw=none]{d}[name=I, anchor=center]{}
      & \cdots \ar[rounded corners,
            to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
                      |- (I.center) \tikztonodes
                      -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
                      -- (\tikztotarget)}]{dll}[at end]{\partial} \\
  {} & H^n(U \cup V) \rar & H^n(U) \oplus H^n(V) \rar & H^n(U \cap V) \rar & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: meyer-viet.png]

### Improvements

This improvement introduces a two-argument style `column width={<col>}{<content>}` that sets the `text width` of the nodes in column `<col>` to the width of `<content>`.
It’s not the best solution as the user needs to input the widest `<content>` of the column itself. One could surely think of either a solution that uses the `.aux` file to save the widest width or a `to path` that checks all `.west` and `.east` anchors of nodes in the same column to check which nodes are the biggest.

The `to path` now doesn’t need an auxiliary node that is placed manually (previously `X`, `Y` and `I`) but uses instead the middle between `\tikztostart` and `\tikztotarget`. The `@find halway` code simply defines `@aux` at this middle point. The code is a `calc`-less version of `($(\tikztostart)!.5!(\tikztotarget)$)`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  commutative diagrams/column width/.style 2 args={
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/matrix of math nodes maybe/.append style={
      column #1/.append style={
        every node/.append style={
          align=center,
          text width=\widthof{\iftikzcd@mathmode$\fi#2\iftikzcd@mathmode$\fi}}}}},
  @find halfway/.code 2 args={%
    \begingroup
      \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointlineattime{.5}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}}%
      \pgfnode{coordinate}{center}{}{@aux}{}%
    \endgroup},
  line break/.style={
    every node/.append style={at end},
    rounded corners, to path={ 
      [@find halfway/.expanded={\tikztostart}{\tikztotarget}]
       -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
       |- (@aux) \tikztonodes
       -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
       -- (\tikztotarget)}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  column width={2}{H^n(U \cup V)},
  column width={3}{H^n(U) \oplus H^n(V)},
  column width={4}{H^n(U \cap V)}
]
0 \rar & H^0(U \cup V) \rar
            & H^0(U) \oplus H^0(V) \rar
                  & H^0(U \cap V) \ar[line break]{dll}{\partial} \\
       & H^1(U \cap V) \rar
            & H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) \rar
                  & H^1(U \cap V) \ar[line break]{dll}{\partial}            & \cdots \rar
            & H^i(U) \oplus H^i(V) \rar
                  & \cdots \ar[line break]{dll}{\partial} \\
       & H^n(U \cup V) \rar
            & H^n(U) \oplus H^n(V) \rar
                  & H^n(U \cap V) \rar
                       & 0
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: There is a way to improve this: by adding `minimum size` for the nodes (but that looks ugly, once when I tried).

Comment: I think the `rounded corners` option can be used for the entire diagram since it applies to every corner that might show up. This would simplify the code slightly.

Comment: Thanks kan, your solution is quite good! i just have one more question: what if I have less than 3 terms in the last row? I tried it and it messes up the last bent arrow

Comment: I solved by filling the voids with `\rar[draw=none] & {}`, surely it's not the most elegant thing but it does the job. Thank you again

Comment: @Alternoia I had been away for the dinner. Glad that you could sort out the problem. BTW, that is how you should salvage your case (as far as I know).

Comment: @kan I have included a (hopefully) improved version of your answer. It uses text width instead of minimum size (which would have also changed the height). Is this the improvement you were talking about in your comment? Of course, OP’s way of using an empty column (containing only `{}` so that a node is created) is another possibility (I’d suggest to use `&[+0pt]`), sadly one has to keep track of all the columns.