# Which package should I use for doing a connecting homomorphism diagram like this in latex

Tags: packages, diagrams, xy-pic, code

which package should I use for doing a diagram like this in latex:

[image]

Comment: Ah, that was supposed to be [tag:xy-pic] (the `\xymatrix` macro is what you are looking for). There are a few [tag:tikz-cd] questions here that are very similar to your image (especially the long arrow): [How to draw bent arrows going to a new line in long formulas (ex. chain complexes)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110470), [How do you draw the "snake" arrow for the connecting homomorphism in the snake lemma?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3892) and [Tikz-cd and snake lemma: "loseness" and centered figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95770).

Comment: That's the Mayer-Vietoris sequence. Couldn't have passed my qualifying exams without it!

Comment: that's right =D

Comment: I don't know `tikz-cd` so perhaps that'll do it., but if not I'd recommend using `tikz` along with `tikzmark`. Then you could easily separate the drawing from the the text, or better still come up with a macro to automate this, but then the trick is really to figure out how you want to specify these types of diagrams.

Comment: I dunno, but if you hit a snake, you go all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 8):

Using [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) package for Commutative Homomorphism diagrams. your diagram was made using `xy-pic` as suggested by Qrrbrbirlbel in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115002/which-package-should-i-use-for-doing-a-diagram-like-this-in-latex/115020#comment254182_115002)

**code for diagram**

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
& H^{k+1}(M) \ar[r]^<<<<<<<<<<<{i^*} & \cdots \\
& H^k(M) \ar[r]^>>>>>{i^*} 
& H^k(U) \oplus H^k(V) \ar[r]^>>>>>{j^*} 
& H^k(U \cap V) \ar `[ul] `[l] `[lllu] |{d^*} `[l] [rlllu] \\
&  *{}  & \cdots \ar[r]^<<<<<<<<<<{j^*} 
& H^{k-1}(U \cap V) \ar `[ul] `[l] `[lllu] |{d^*} `[l] [rlllu] }
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possibility using [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
curarrow/.style={
rounded corners=8pt,
execute at begin to={every node/.style={fill=red}},
to path={-- ([xshift=50pt]\tikztostart.center)
  |- (#1) node[fill=white] {$\scriptstyle d^*$}
  -| ([xshift=-40pt]\tikztotarget.center)
  -- (\tikztotarget)}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={text height=2ex,text depth=0.75ex}}]
  {} & & H^{k+1}(M) \arrow{r}{i^*} & \cdots \\
  {} & & H^k(M) \arrow{r}{i^*} & H^k(U) \oplus H^k(V) \arrow{r}{j^*}
  \arrow[draw=none]{u}[name=Y, shape=coordinate]{}
  \arrow[draw=none]{d}[name=Z,shape=coordinate]{}
  & H^k(U \cap V) \arrow[curarrow=Y]{ull}{} \\
  & & & \cdots \arrow{r}{j^*} & H^{k-1}(U \cap V)
  \arrow[curarrow=Z]{ull}{} \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution using tikz

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{tight}  = [outer sep=0,inner sep=0]
        \tikzstyle{myarr}  = [-stealth]
        \tikzstyle{myline} = [-,tight]
        \node (v1) at (1,0)     {$\dots$};
        \node (v2) at (3.5,0)   {$H^{k-1}\left(U \bigcap V \right)$};
        \node (v5) at (0,1)     {$d*$};
        \node (v13) at (0,3)    {$d*$};
        \node (v8) at (-3.5,2)  {$H^k\left( M \right)$};
        \node (v9) at (0,2)     {$H^k\left( U \right) \otimes H^k\left( V \right)$};
        \node (v10) at (3.5,2)  {$H^{k}\left(U \bigcap V \right)$};
        \node (v16) at (-3.5,4) {$H^{k+1}\left( M \right)$};    
        \node (v17) at (-1,4)   {$\dots$};      
        \draw [myline](5,0)  node (v3)  {} .. controls (6,0) and (6,1)   .. (5,1)  node (v4) {};    
        \draw [myline](-5,1) node (v6)  {} .. controls (-6,1) and (-6,2) .. (-5,2) node (v7) {};
        \draw [myline](5,2)  node (v11) {} .. controls (6,2) and (6,3)   .. (5,3)  node (v12) {};
        \draw [myline](-5,3) node (v14) {} .. controls (-6,3) and (-6,4) .. (-5,4) node (v15) {};   
        \node at (2,0.25) {$j*$};
        \node at (-2,2.25) {$i*$};
        \node at (2,2.25) {$j*$};
        \node at (-2,4.25) {$i*$};

        \draw [myarr] (v1) edge (v2);
        \draw [myarr] (v7) edge (v8);
        \draw [myarr] (v8) edge (v9);
        \draw [myarr] (v9) edge (v10);
        \draw [myarr] (v15) edge (v16);
        \draw [myarr] (v16) edge (v17);

        \draw [myline] (v2) edge (v3);
        \draw [myline] (v4) edge (v5);
        \draw [myline] (v5) edge (v6);
        \draw [myline] (v10) edge (v11);
        \draw [myline] (v12) edge (v13);
        \draw [myline] (v13) edge (v14);    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces result like this:

[image]

Comment: If you want the asterisks to be superscripted, just replace `i*` with `i^*` and so on.

Comment: Yeah sure, I missed that, trivial....

Comment: Also, it looks like `\otimes` should be replaced with `\oplus`, and `\bigcap` should be replaced with `\cap`.