# I want to draw a nice connecting homomorphism arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\node (A) at (0,0) {$0$};
\node (B) at (1,0) {$H^0(G,P)$};
\node (C) at (2,0) {$H^0(G,M)$};
\node (D) at (3,0) {$H^0(G,N)$};
\node (E) at (1,-1) {$H^1(G,P)$};
\node (F) at (2,-1) {$H^1(G,M)$};
\node (G) at (3,-1) {$H^1(G,N)$};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize,>=angle 90]
(A) edge node[above]{} (B)
(B) edge node[above]{$\phi$} (C)
(C) edge node[above]{$\psi$} (D)
(D) edge node[above]{} (E)
(E) edge node[above]{} (F)
(F) edge node[above]{} (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

So I've got this that I want to try and draw a 'nice' connecting homomorphism which I'll try my best to describe: It starts from the end of the last element in the first row and ends at the beginning of the first element in the second row.

Maybe it's better to do it in tikzcd but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3892/15925

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With TikZ only

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes,column sep=15pt,row sep=15pt]{
  0 & H^0(G,P) & H^0(G,M) & H^0(G,N) \\
    & H^1(G,P) & H^1(G,M) & H^1(G,N) \\
};
\draw[->,font=\scriptsize,every node/.style={above},rounded corners]
  (m-1-1) edge (m-1-2) 
  (m-1-2) edge["$\phi$"] (m-1-3)
  (m-1-3) edge["$\psi$"] (m-1-4)
  (m-1-4.east) --+(5pt,0)|-+(0,-7.5pt)-|([xshift=-5pt]m-2-2.west)--(m-2-2.west)
  (m-2-2) edge (m-2-3)
  (m-2-3) edge (m-2-4)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: How may I add in $\delta$ as a label on the longest arrow?

Comment: @HaikalYeo: You can add `node[pos=<num>]{$\delta$} to the 4th line after the `\draw` command. Depending on where on the line you want `$\delta$` to be, you may want to put the `node` code before or after the coordinates, and then use `pos` to adjust its position.

Comment: Sorry if I sound really stupid here but do I replace node and num with something else?

Comment: Ooh. I get it already. Except I don't know how to adjust <num>

Comment: @HaikalYeo: `<num>` is a number between `0` and `1`, which controls  the position of the node on a path. For example, `(m-1-4.east) --+(5pt,0)|-+(0,-7.5pt)-|node[pos=.25]{$\delta$}([xshift=-5pt]m-2-2.west)--(m-2-2.west)` will put the node at the middle of the longest line.

Answer (score 21):

With `tikz-cd` it's a piece of cake:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[scale=1.5]
0 \arrow{r} &
H^0(G,P) \arrow{r}{\phi} &
H^0(G,M) \arrow{r}{\psi} &
H^0(G,N) \arrow{dll} \\
&
H^1(G,P) \arrow{r} &
H^1(G,M) \arrow{r} &
H^1(G,N)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a modification of the example in the documentation at the end of page 11 we can get a bent arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}           
0 \arrow{r} &
H^0(G,P) \arrow{r}{\phi} &
H^0(G,M) \arrow{r}{\psi} \arrow[phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z}]{d} &
H^0(G,N)
  \arrow[
    rounded corners,
    to path={
      -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
      |- (Z) [near end]\tikztonodes
      -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
      -- (\tikztotarget)
    }
  ]{dll} \\
&
H^1(G,P) \arrow{r} &
H^1(G,M) \arrow{r} &
H^1(G,N)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to bend the arrow such that it starts at the right side of H^0(G,N) and then ends at the left side of H^1(G,P), making an inverted S shape?

Comment: @HaikalYeo Yes, it's possible. I'm not saying I fully understand the code, I just adapted it from an example in the documentation.

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to? May I have the link to it?

Comment: @HaikalYeo The documentation of `tikz-cd`; you should have it on your system, but you can find it online at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

Comment: I used the exact same code but there is an additional down arrow from H^0(G,M) to H^1(G,M). How do I remove this?

Comment: @HaikalYeo First of all, ensure you have an up-to-date TeX distribution

Comment: I'm writing this on SAGE. Is that not up to date? :/

Comment: @HaikalYeo I have no idea what you mean about SAGE; it is not a TeX distribution. What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm using a Mac if that's what you're asking.

https://cloud.sagemath.com/

Comment: @HaikalYeo Launch "TeX Live Utility" and do a full update.

Comment: How may I add in $\delta$ as a label on the longest arrow?