# Arrows in a commutative diagram are slanted in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I have the following commutative diagram in TikZ:

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix (b) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em]
            {
                D(0) & D(1) & \cdots & C \\
                C & C & \cdots & C \\
            };
            \path[->, font=\scriptsize]
            (b-1-1) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{g_0}\)} (b-1-2) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{\phi_0}\)} (b-2-1)
            (b-1-2) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{\phi_1}\)} (b-2-2) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{g_1}\)} (b-1-3)
            (b-1-3) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{\phi_i}\)} (b-2-3) edge (b-1-4)
            (b-2-1) edge[-,double] (b-2-2)
            (b-2-2) edge[-,double] (b-2-3)
            (b-2-3) edge[-,double] (b-2-4)
            (b-1-4) edge[-,double] (b-2-4);
        \end{tikzpicture}.
    \end{center}
```

When I render it, I end up with weird slanted lines going into the dots.

[image: slanted arrows]

The problem is even more extreme if I just use \dots.  How can I fix this to make the lines straight? I'm aware that tikz-cd probably fixes this, but I don't have time at the moment to learn the syntax and convert everything, so I'm still doing things the old way for now.

Comment: Add `anchor=center`: `\matrix (b) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em,
   nodes={anchor=center}] ....` .

Comment: Hi Harry.  For future reference, even without learning the syntax of `tikz-cd` then its `asymmetric rectangle` node shape is really useful for this.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3894/86 for an example.

Comment: @LoopSpace Great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tikz-cd` for this job.

The syntax is much simpler and the arrow labels are typeset correctly in script style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
D(0) \arrow[r,"g_0"] \arrow[d,"\phi_0"] &
D(1) \arrow[r,"g_1"] \arrow[d,"\phi_1"] &
\cdots \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"\phi_i"] &
C \arrow[d,equal]
\\
C \arrow[r,equal] & C \arrow[r,equal] & \cdots \arrow[r,equal] & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use phantoms to make the arrow straight. Note that I removed the wrong `font=\scriptsize` declaration.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (b) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em]
  {
   D(0) & D(1) & \cdots\vphantom{()} & C\vphantom{()} \\
   C & C & \cdots\vphantom{C} & C \\
  };
  \path[->]
  (b-1-1) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{g_0}\)} (b-1-2) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{\phi_0}\)} (b-2-1)
  (b-1-2) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{\phi_1}\)} (b-2-2) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{g_1}\)} (b-1-3)
  (b-1-3) edge node[auto]{\(\scriptstyle{\phi_i}\)} (b-2-3) edge (b-1-4)
  (b-2-1) edge[-,double] (b-2-2)
  (b-2-2) edge[-,double] (b-2-3)
  (b-2-3) edge[-,double] (b-2-4)
  (b-1-4) edge[-,double] (b-2-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Old style]

Comment: I'm aware tikz-cd is better for this, but I have like 100 diagrams in the older pre-tikz-cd style, and I'm not ready to fix it yet.  If you're aware of a way to quickly fix a whole bunch of these at once, I'm all ears.

Comment: @HarryGindi Sorry, you used the wrong tool. I'll try a fix for the other style, but the typesetting of labels is really awful.

Comment: @HarryGindi Here it is. But conversion is quite easy, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix to your problem is to add the following line just below \begin{tikzpicture}:

```
 \tikzset{every node/.style={anchor=center, text centered}}
```

This gives me (I use TeXstudio + XeLaTeX, but it shouldn't make a difference):

[image: Diagram with nodes properly aligned]