# Snake-lemma and making the connective morphism pass under the others

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

i'm trying to draw the snake-lemma diagram but the connective morphism is no passing under the other ones as i would like to (it IS passing under, but not with enough spacing, the second image should clarify what i mean) and i would also like to move its label, like the second figure.

[image: Snake-lemma]

[image: Snake-lemma how i want it]

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
{} & \red{\ker f'} \arrow[r, "\overline{\alpha}", red] \arrow[d, hook, "i'"] & \red{\ker f} \arrow[r, "\overline{\beta}", red] \arrow[d, hook, "i"] & \red{\ker f''} \arrow[d, hook, "i''"] 
\arrow[ddd, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z}] \arrow[dddll,
    "\delta",
    rounded corners,
    to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
              |- (Z) [near end]\tikztonodes
              -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
              -- (\tikztotarget)}, red] & {}\\
{} & M' \arrow[r, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "f'"] & M \arrow[r, "\beta"] \arrow[d, "f"] & M'' \arrow[r] \arrow[d, "f''"] & 0 \\
0 \arrow[r] & N' \arrow[r, "\alpha'"] \arrow[d, two heads, "\pi'"] & N \arrow[r, "\beta'"] \arrow[d, two heads, "\pi"] & N'' \arrow[d, two heads, "\pi''"] & {} \\
{} & \red{\coker f'} \arrow[r, "\overline{\alpha'}", red] & \red{\coker f} \arrow[r, "\overline{\beta'}", red] & \red{\coker f''} & {}
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/how-do-you-draw-the-snake-arrow-for-the-connecting-homomorphism-in-the-snake-l

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a way to tell tikzcd that
f, f', f'' come with white backgrounds.
For instance
`\def\atfield[#1]{\arrow[#1,nodes={fill=white}]}`

You may also use `preaction={draw=white,-,line width=3}`
to create white background for arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\def\red#1{|[red]|#1}
\def\coker{\operatorname{coker}}
\def\atfield[#1]{\arrow[#1,preaction={draw=white,-,line width=3},nodes={fill=white}]}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
{} & \red{\ker f'} \arrow[r, "\overline{\alpha}", red] \arrow[d, hook, "i'"] & \red{\ker f} \arrow[r, "\overline{\beta}", red] \arrow[d, hook, "i"] & \red{\ker f''} \arrow[d, hook, "i''"] 
\arrow[ddd, phantom, ""{coordinate, name=Z}] \arrow[dddll,
    "\qquad\delta",
    rounded corners,
    to path={ -- ([xshift=2ex]\tikztostart.east)
              |- (Z) [near end]\tikztonodes
              -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west)
              -- (\tikztotarget)}, red] & {}\\
{} & M' \arrow[r, "\alpha"] \atfield[d, "f'"] & M \arrow[r, "\beta"] \atfield[d, "f"] & M'' \arrow[r] \atfield[d, "f''"] & 0 \\
0 \arrow[r] & N' \arrow[r, "\alpha'"] \arrow[d, two heads, "\pi'"] & N \arrow[r, "\beta'"] \arrow[d, two heads, "\pi"] & N'' \arrow[d, two heads, "\pi''"] & {} \\
{} & \red{\coker f'} \arrow[r, "\overline{\alpha'}", red] & \red{\coker f} \arrow[r, "\overline{\beta'}", red] & \red{\coker f''} & {}
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use `tikz-cd` but is based on the answer given at [How do you draw the "snake" arrow for the connecting homomorphism in the snake lemma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3892/) .  The sizes of the gaps are partly hard coded as they have to encompass both the node and the edge.  I haven't adapted it to your labels, but that should be straight forward (I recommend using the `asymmetrical rectangle` node so that the `alpha` and `beta` labels are aligned horizontally).

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611629/86}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{%
  matrix,%
  calc,%
  arrows%
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 60]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep={60pt,between origins},row sep={60pt,between origins},nodes={asymmetrical rectangle}] (s)
{
&|[name=ka]| \ker f &|[name=kb]| \ker g &|[name=kc]| \ker h \\
%
&|[name=A]| A' &|[name=B]| B' &|[name=C]| C' &|[name=01]| 0 \\
%
|[name=02]| 0 &|[name=A']| A &|[name=B']| B &|[name=C']| C \\
%
&|[name=ca]| \coker f &|[name=cb]| \coker g &|[name=cc]| \coker h \\
};
\draw[->] (ka) edge (A)
          (kb) edge (B)
          (kc) edge (C)
          (A) edge (B)
          (B) edge node[auto] {\(p\)} (C)
          (C) edge (01)
          (A) edge node[auto,asymmetrical rectangle] (f) {\(f\)} (A')
          (B) edge node[auto,asymmetrical rectangle] (g) {\(g\)} (B')
          (C) edge node[auto,asymmetrical rectangle] (h) {\(h\)} (C')
          (02) edge (A')
          (A') edge node[auto] {\(i\)} (B')
          (B') edge (C')
          (A') edge (ca)
          (B') edge (cb)
          (C') edge (cc)
;
\draw[->,gray] (ka) edge (kb)
               (kb) edge (kc)
               (ca) edge (cb)
               (cb) edge (cc)
;
\draw[->,gray,rounded corners] (kc) -| node[auto,text=black,pos=.7] {\(\partial\)} ($(01.east)+(.5,0)$)  |-
(h.mid east) (h.mid west) +(-.1,0) --
(g.mid east) (g.mid west) +(-.1,0) --
(f.mid east) (f.mid west) +(-.1,0)
 -| ($(02.west)+(-.5,0)$) |- (ca);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: snake lemma with gaps]

Comment: Actually, the `asymmetrical rectangle` shape doesn't solve that problem.